# Writing to WAV file causes struct.error: required argument is not an integer

Tags: python-3.x, wav

This might be a stupid question, as I'm very new to python, but I'm trying to write a sine wave to a file in python, and I keep getting the error that the required argument is not an integer. I know that this means I need to pass in a non-decimal number to the function, but no matter what I do to make it an int, it doesn't work. I'm using the wave library, and numpy for the calculations. There error is always at the writeframes(*data*) line (23). My current code is:

```
import wave

import numpy as np

samples = [int()]

tones = int(input("How many notes do you want?"))

sRate = 44100           # 44.1kHz sample rate
nSamples = sRate * float(input("How long for each tone?")) * tones

x = np.arange(nSamples)/float(sRate)
hz = int(input("What frequency do you want it to start on?"))
vals = (32767*np.sin(2.0*math.pi*hz*x))+16384
newArr = []
for x in range(len(vals)):
    newArr.append(int(vals[x]))
file = wave.open("sine"+str(hz)+"_"+str(tones)+".wav", 'wb')
file.setparams((1, 2, sRate, nSamples, 'NONE', 'uncompressed'))
for x in newArr:
    print(type(x))
    file.writeframesraw(x)
file.close()
```

The input prompts don't do much right now, I've just added them so it is easier in the future. I have also noticed that the error says at another part that a bytes-like object is required. Even if I typecast `x` to a byte, I still get the error.

Here is the error and the type that gets printed:

```
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/smack/Seagate Portable Drive/Programs/music/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    file.writeframesraw(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 426, in writeframesraw
    data = memoryview(data).cast('B')
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
Exception ignored in: <function Wave_write.__del__ at 0x7fa20a05c280>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 327, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 445, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 468, in _ensure_header_written
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 480, in _write_header
struct.error: required argument is not an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the error with its stacktrace?

Comment: I just did, I think that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Presently I have figured out, how to write a wav-file in python. And I found there is a nice way using sciypy. Scipy has the method `scipy.io.wavfile.write`.

I rewrote your example program using this scipy function. Now it runs, hope it helps.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile

samples = [int()]

tones = int(input("How many notes do you want?"))

sRate = 44100           # 44.1kHz sample rate
nSamples = sRate * float(input("How long for each tone?")) * tones

x = np.arange(nSamples)/float(sRate)
hz = int(input("What frequency do you want it to start on?"))
vals = (32767*np.sin(2.0*math.pi*hz*x))+16384
newArr = []
for x in range(len(vals)):
    newArr.append(int(vals[x]))

newArr = np.asarray(newArr,dtype=np.int16)
scipy.io.wavfile.write("sine"+str(hz)+"_"+str(tones)+".wav",sRate,newArr)
```